# Integrating out fields from classical systems

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, terminology, field-theory, classical-field-theory

Has anyone ever heard of integrating out fields from classical Lagrangians if they are quadratic?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, a Lagrangian $L = \partial_i \phi \partial^i \phi + m^2\phi^2$ has the same equation of movement that the Lagrangian $L' = \partial_i \phi \partial^i \phi + m^2(F\phi - \frac{F^2}{2})$.

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $L'$ simply give $\Box \phi +m^2F=0$ and $ F = \phi$, so we have $\Box \phi +m^2\phi=0$, which are the Euler-Lagrange equations for $L$.

$F$ is then just an auxiliary field variable, so $L'$ is just an alternative presentation for $L$.